# CountVectorizer().fit in scikit-learn Python gives Memory error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on an 8 class classification problem, Training set contains around 400,000 labeled entities, I am using CountVectorizer.fit() to vectorize the data, but I am getting a Memory error, I tried using HashingVectorizer instead, but in vain.

```
path = 'data/products.tsv' products = pd.read_table(path , header= None , names = ['label' , 'entry'])   
X = products.entry
y = products.label
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# Vectorizing the Dataset
vect = CountVectorizer()
vect.fit(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Do you preprocess your text data or not ?
The point here is that you have a lot of samples and you don't provide any dictionnary for your Counter nor using a "stop_word" list.
The vectors generated are thus of a high dimension, and since you have 400k example, if your laptop does not have enough memory your get a Memory Error

Comment: you got a MemoryError with HashVectorizer?

Comment: @MMF I didn't preprocess the data, I'll keep this in mind next time

Comment: @elyase Yes, I tried using HashVectorizer, but it gave me the same error.

Comment: @IbrahimSharaf skleanr uses optimized operations (sparse representations, iterators etc...) but if your amount of data is really huge it's still problematic. So what I suggest is that you clean as much as you can your data and then rerun your code ;)

Comment: @MMF I see, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can set `max_features` which limit the memory usage of your vocabulary.
The right value really depends on the task so you should treat it as a hyper parameter and try and tune it. In NLP (english) people usually use ~10,000 as a vocabulary size. You can also do the same with `HashVectorizer` but you risk hash collusions which will cause multiple words to increase the same counter.

```
path = 'data/products.tsv' products = pd.read_table(path , header= None , names = ['label' , 'entry'])   
X = products.entry
y = products.label
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

# Vectorizing the Dataset
vect = CountVectorizer(max_features=10000)
vect.fit(X_train.values.astype('U'))
X_train_dtm = vect.transform(X_train)
X_test_dtm = vect.transform(X_test)
```